# Python: How do you display/loop a sequence of numbers from an array using functions and loops? Visual Metronome

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops

Ok, so new to coding and I've managed to piece this together from PTHW by Zed Shaw, Google, and some existing help on here.

I can't seem to figure out how to loop through the sequence of numbers in the array one by one displaying only one at a time. This is only going to be a visual thing. V2 is the one that needs help. Thanks in advance for any help and explanation!

**V1** works, but only prints "tick" in time in terminal.

```
#Accepts user's beats per minute and turns it into variable "x"
x = int(raw_input("BPM:"))

#Calculates floating point BPM instances in seconds
metspeed = 60.0 / x 

#no idea
import threading 

#function definition. No idea how, but it can print in desired time.
def visual():
    threading.Timer(metspeed, visual).start()   
    print "tick"

#function call  
visual()
```

**V2** Doesn't work at all.

```
#2 This is my attempt at looping through the array. Doesn't work.
x = int(raw_input("BPM:"))

metspeed = 60.0 / x 

#Number array. Better way if numbers go above 4?
i = [1, 2, 3, 4] 

import threading 

#attempt to pull from array and displaying only 1 number at a time.
#seems like a loop is needed, and a way to stop the loop without control-c
def visual():
    threading.Timer(metspeed, visual).start()   
    print "%s\r" % i,

visual()
```

Comment: Did you try using while loop ?

Comment: You should definitely read more about Timer objects too: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Answer (score 1):

What about simply using `time.sleep`?

```py
import time

x = int(raw_input("BPM:"))
metspeed = 60.0 / x

i = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for j in i:
    print j
    time.sleep(metspeed)
```

If you want to run it forever (or until the user interrupts with Ctrl-C), use a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    print "tick"
    time.sleep(metspeed)
```

Comment: I think it's supposed to keep looping until interrupted. This will only go through the loop once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cycle` to cycle over a list.

```
from itertools import cycle
from threading import Timer

counts = cycle(xrange(1, 5))

def visual():
    print next(counts)
    Timer(metspeed, visual).start()

visual()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it.

```
x = int(raw_input("BPM:"))
metspeed = 60.0 / x 
import threading
import random

i = [1, 2, 3, 4] 

def visual():
   print random.choice(i)

mythread = threading.Timer(metspeed, visual) 
mythread.start()              ## start you thread process
myvar = False                 ## write a condition when it should stop
if myvar == False:            ## check if the condition is met
    mythread.cancel()         ## stop the triggering of timer
```